# replace date format in a text file name used as an argument in a subscript of a main bash script. Further explained

Tags: bash

Sample code

I have a main bash script, which takes dd/mm/yyyy as one of the argument that is  used to replace the possible combination of date format comes in filename.

```
 sh mainscript.sh dd/mm/yyyy
```

There is a sub script function resides in it

```
SubscriptFn FileName Date SubScriptName
```

Subscript function

```
SubscriptFn(){
#$1- FileName
#$2- Date
#$3- SubScriptName
local strFileTmp=$1;
local dtTmp=$2;  --> This is coming from the main script argument
local mm = ${dtTmp:3:2}; local dd; local yy
#replace date format of a filename
strFileTmp = ${strFileTmp//"yymmdd"/$yy$mm$dd} 

    sh "$3" strFileTmp
}
```

FYI-SubScriptName.sh ($3) is used to filter the strFileTmp data using some other file data (abc.csv), and looks like as below

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $5 in a' abc_yymmdd.csv FS='|'
```

Now my other file (abc.csv) also contains the date in its name,I am not able to find a way to use the main script date to parse the date format in abc.csv file.

Can someone please help?